# How to edit Entity which spans over 4 tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

**Important: I have edited the question to reflect Jannagy02's answer, which eliminates the Dropdownlist issue**

I have a conceptual question regarding ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework.

First, lets take a look at my model:[image: EDM]

This all ads up to one device. One device has a category, a manufacturer, a status and 0..n comments to it. This is stripped down. I did not want to go overboard with complexity, while learning MVC. So lets just focus on `Device` and  `Category` while ignoring things like Repository and Unit of Work patterns.

After I had set this up, and the scaffolding did its magic, the view generated only showed the `Name` property of the device.

My plan is, that while creating or updating a device the user (not admin) can only choose from categories already existant. Hence a Dropdownlist.

For this I have created a ViewModel:

```
public class DeviceEditViewModel
{
    public Device dev { get; set; }

    public int? SelectedManufactor { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Manufactors { get; set; }

    public int? SelectedCategory { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoriesListItems { get; set; }
}
```

The GET Edit Method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var device = db.Devices.Find(id);
    var vm = new DeviceEditViewModel
                 {
                      dev = device,
                      Categories = db.Categories.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem 
                      {
                          Value = x.ID.ToString(), 
                          Text = x.Name, 
                          Selected = x == device.Category
                      })
                  };
    return View(vm);
}
```

Here comes my first problem: The generated dropdownlist does not fetch the actual category of the device. So how I do I select the actual category as the selected value?

Second, how to I inject this selected ListItem as the category of the device model when I hit the save button and how does this reflect in the post method, which looks like this:

```
//Edited to reflect answer
public ActionResult Edit(DeviceEditViewModel editViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Device device = editViewModel.dev;
        if (editViewModel.SelectedCategory != null)
        {
            Category selectedCat = db.Categories.Single(x => x.ID == editViewModel.SelectedCategory.Value);
            device.Category = selectedCat;
        }

        db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(editViewModel);
}
```

This is the DropDownList part of my view:

```
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dev.Category, new { @class = "control-label" })

    <div class="controls">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoriesListItems, Model.CategoriesListItems)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dev.Category, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem which remains, lies in the POST method. I have written it a bit longer to be able to debug it better. The actual issue is:

Device gets updated with a category, but after the `db.SaveChanges()` call it does not get written to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First modify you ViewModel so that it can contain the selected value:

```
public class DeviceEditViewModel
{
    public Device dev { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Manufactors { get; set; }

    public int? SelectedCategory { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Status { get; set; }
}
```

Second:

In the View bind the SelectedCategory so that it can posted:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategory, m.Categories)
```

or use this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategory, new SelectList(m.Categories, "ValuePropertyName", "TextPropertyName"))
```

And Post the ViewModel to the Edit not the Device:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(DeviceEditViewModel devm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        devm.device.CategoryId = devm.SelectedCategory; // <- Main thing to do
        db.Entry(devm.device).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(devm);
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem of creating the Dropdownlist correctly, but not the POST method issue. I can save the `editviewmodel.dev` part, but that only incorporates the `name` not the `category.`

Comment: Just added some modifications, I dont know if it helps. Your device's category won't be modified by your view. You have to made it yourself based on selected value of dropdown.

Comment: I have implemented your changes in my opening post, but there is still some strange behaviour. I have changed on device to cat "Router", and stepped through the POST method. It changes the Category to the ID 1 which is router and saves it. But upon returning to the index it is still on the old ID for Smartphone.

Comment: But the Device is saved correctly? If it is, then it could be some caching issue by your browser.

Comment: no it is not saved. The saving does not happe, although `db.SaveChanges()` is called. I have rechecked through a different browser and by looking at the tables. No changes are made.

Comment: But you get the correct SelectedCategory set it to the device and call db.SaveChanges() it throws no error and it is not saved. It is really wierd :)

Comment: Yes, If I change the name the change gets saved. Only the Category change does not get saved.

Answer (score 0):

After I let the issue rest for a few days, I found a working solution. the last problem of actually editing the item and its properties AND saving it to the database, was pretty trivial once I manged to narrow down the places of where the error could occur.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(DeviceEditViewModel editViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //non-working: Device device = editViewmodel.env;
        Device device = db.Devices.Single(x => x.Id == editViewModel.dev.Id); /*working*/
        if (editViewModel.SelectedCategory != null)
        {
           device.Category = db.Categories.Where(x => x.ID == editViewModel.SelectedCategory).Select(x => x).Single();
        }
        db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Devices.AddOrUpdate(device);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
        return View(editViewModel);
}
```

Instead of using the Viewmodel which was used I fetched the device to be edited from the database by comparing the IDs and called AddOrUpdate() on this entity.

Works like a charm now. I will however give the solution click to my dropdownlist helper answer. Would not be fair otherwise.